# MTOM - Unexpected EOF in prolog at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]

Tags: soap, postman, mtom

I'm trying to send `multipart/related` request through postman. But I'm getting error:

```
<soap:Reason>
    <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]</soap:Text>
</soap:Reason>
```

**Endpoint:** POST https://sdummy.test.net/enterprise/soap?ServiceName=IntegrationManagementService

**Headers I'm using:**

```
Content-Type:multipart/related; start="<rootpart*7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4@example.jaxws.sun.com>"; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4"; start-info="text/xml"
Soapaction:http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2011/05/management/IntegrationManagementService#submitLargeDocument
Accept:text/xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *;q=.2, */*; q=.2
User-Agent:Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Host:sdummy.test.net
```

**Payload:**

```
--uuid:7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4
Content-Id: <rootpart*7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/03/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2011/05/management">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsa:MessageID>ps_sd_7701</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:Action>http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07/action/import</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07/addressing/queue</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <wsa:submitLargeDocument>
            <wsa:Document>
                <Include xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:51349b7a-562a-4e98-ab8c-736cfecb03eb@example.jaxws.sun.com"/>
            </wsa:Document>
        </wsa:submitLargeDocument>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--uuid:7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4
Content-Id:<51349b7a-562a-4e98-ab8c-736cfecb03eb@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    <ImportEntities>
        <Candidate>
            <EmailAddress>test11@mailinator.com</EmailAddress>
        </Candidate>
    </ImportEntities>
--uuid:7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4--
```

[image]

**Postman Generated cURL command:**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://stghilton.taleo.net/enterprise/soap?ServiceName=IntegrationManagementService' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/related; start="<rootpart*7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4@example.jaxws.sun.com>"; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4"; start-info="text/xml"' \
--header 'Soapaction: http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2011/05/management/IntegrationManagementService#submitLargeDocument' \
--header 'Accept: text/xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *;q=.2, */*; q=.2' \
--header 'User-Agent: Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5' \
--header 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' \
--header 'Host: stghilton.taleo.net' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic UGhlbm9tOj80K2pTSlAz' \
--data-raw '--uuid:7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4
Content-Id: <rootpart*7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
<?xml version='\''1.0'\'' encoding='\''UTF-8'\''?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/03/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2011/05/management">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsa:MessageID>ps_sd_7701</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:Action>http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07/action/import</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07/addressing/queue</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <wsa:submitLargeDocument>
            <wsa:Document>
                <Include xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:51349b7a-562a-4e98-ab8c-736cfecb03eb@example.jaxws.sun.com"/>
            </wsa:Document>
        </wsa:submitLargeDocument>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--uuid:7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4
Content-Id:<51349b7a-562a-4e98-ab8c-736cfecb03eb@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    <ImportEntities>
        <Candidate>
            <EmailAddress>test11@mailinator.com</EmailAddress>
        </Candidate>
    </ImportEntities>
--uuid:7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4--'
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Are you sure you custom content type header is actually used ? I see postman's "Text" body type is used, which means it could override your custom with text/plain...

Comment: Hi @GPI, what should be used in that case? Could you please help me with this

Comment: To help debugging, could you add to your question what is displayed by postman's "code snippet" tab (right of the send button), which would spell out the request as it is sent in another format, e.g. `cURL`.

Comment: Added postman generated cURL command @GPI

Comment: Thank you. At first sight, things look mostly OK. One missing thing (but I do not know if it is normatively important) is the content-type's `start` attribute, which should be the content id or the XML part, so `"<rootpart*7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4@example.jaxws.sun.com>"` in your case. Are you also sure the server endpoint accepts XOP+MTOM ?

Comment: I updated the ```start ``` attribute. Still same error @GPI. Updated my description with start attribute

Comment: Hi @GPI can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a purely technical point of view the only error I can see is your handling of the multipart structure.

More precisely, you need to skip a line (blank line) between the headers of each part and their body, e.g change the 3 lines :

```
Content-Id: <rootpart*7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
<?xml version='\''1.0'\'' encoding='\''UTF-8'\''?>
```

To 4 lines :

```
Content-Id: <rootpart*7661941e-06d9-4961-af10-db612c7ffcc4@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version='\''1.0'\'' encoding='\''UTF-8'\''?>
```

At each part, e.g. also here :

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
<ImportEntities>
```

To

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<ImportEntities>
```

It is mandatory in multipart content to split the header from the body by a blank line.